# pyrocms theme error drivers/Session_cookie.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm new to PyroCMS and I'm currently working on a news website which requires the blog functionality. In order not to have my urls displaying "blog" I duplicated the blog module and renamed it "posts" which worked fine.

But now when I view a post I get the following error at the top of the page:

"A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/newerawe/public_html/addons/default/themes/era/theme.php:1)

Filename: drivers/Session_cookie.php

Line Number: 701"

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't mention the most crucial information of all, what php and pyro version you are using .. i have to assume you are using PHP 5.4 the PyroCMS 2.2.

There is something sent before a header, PyroCMS had some problems with this kind of stuff, because PHP has gotten a bit more strict and is throwing several warnings if for example you are trying to create a variable out of thin air:

This will issues an warning saying that `$text` hasn't been defined, and that happens before the headers, which causes the problem.

`// Warning: "Creating default object from empty value" errors
$text->string = 'My text is fine';`

You nead you need to either find and fix the problems, which is a long shot:

`$text = new stdClass();
$text->string = 'My text is fine';`

or try exclude E_WARNING from error_reporting, and you should be fine.

`error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);`

Hope that it helps!